# Slider Is not getting added in kendo Grid ! column lock is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to add frozen columns in my kendo grid column name and data are stored in two diff database tables and both are loading dynamically. No of column are more so I want to frozen few columns so for that I set locked property to true for few columns but it is not working.I am adding code.Please help me to find out solution.

1.This is code to load column names:

```
GetGeneretedColumnsLookupCategories: function () {
    var a = false;
    return MasterObject._columnInTable.map(function (name) {
        if ((name == "Name") || (name == "Description") || (name == "LookupCategoryID")) {
            a = true;
        } else {
            a = false;
        }

        return {
            field: name,
            locked: a,
            width: 140,
            headerTemplate:
            "<div class='ColumnName' id='ver' style='cursor: pointer;' 
            title='Click to sort'>" + name + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon- 
            arrow-up sorting' style='float:right;' id=" + name + "></span> 
            </div>"

        };
    })
},
```

2.This Is code to load datasource:

```
setMastergridDataSource: function () {
    var getLookUpValuesURL = $("#getLookUpValuesURL").val();
    if (MasterObject._sortingParameter._sortParameter == null) {
        MasterObject._sortingParameter._sortParameter = 
        MasterObject._columnInTable[0];
    }
    $("#" + MasterObject._sortingParameter._sortParameter).css("visibility", 
     "visible");
    var weapon = MasterObject._columnInTable;
    var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        serverPaging: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: getLookUpValuesURL,
                datatype: "json",
                cache: false,
                data: function () {
                    return {
                        tableName: MasterObject._dropDownTableSelection,
                        firstColumn: "Name",
                        sortorder: MasterObject._sortingParameter._sortOrder
                        sortBy: MasterObject._sortingParameter._sortParameter
                    };
                }
            }
        },


        schema: {    
            total: function () {
                return MasterObject._countOfTableRecords;
            }   
        },

    });
    debugger;

    $("#Mastergrid").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(datasource);
    MasterObject._sortingParameter._sortParameter = null;
    MasterObject._sortingParameter._sortOrder = "DESC";
```

},

3.To register the gride

```
RegisterMastergrid:

function () {
    debugger;



        $("#Mastergrid").kendoGrid({
            height:550,
            sortable: false,
            reorderable: true,
            scrollable: true,
            selectable: "row",
            resizable: true,
            editable: false,

            pageable: {
                pageSizes: [10, 15, 20, 25],
                pageSize: 10
            },             

            change: function (e) {
                debugger;

                MasterObject._selectedRow = this.select().closest("tr").children("td");
            }
        });

    },
```

This is how grid is getting display,there are total 9 columns but it showing only locked columns.
[image]